# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql, Version=13.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The possible answer posted above is wrong.

Cannot debug a project because of this error message.

**

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql,
>   Version=13.0.0.0

**

The project type is a VSIX extension.

I'm guessing that somehow, the VS SQL support has been whacked somehow... but not sure what to do to fix.

I found this in Add/Remove programs, but do not know how they were installed (maybe through VS install?).
[image: 2016 version of SQL]

My VS Version is:

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Try to 'unload' your project, edit the .csproj and remove the corresponding lines. Thereafter, add your reference again.

Comment: I had already looked at that solution and it has nothing to do with VSIX project.  Thanks though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was causing the issues, I wanted to provide a listing of all classes in assemblies to user to see versioning.  When I commented it out, problem disappeared.

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.GetTypes()).ToList();
```

I still don't know why I have the 2016 SSMS installs, maybe I tried it out earlier this summer.  But, oddly why does this line of code above cause the problem?  Weird.